# P4 triggers: Can I Get Changelist Number And Still Have Option To Revert?

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to write a P4 trigger that sends the changelist number to a downstream reporting tool, when a user commits. As I understand it, I need to use the `change-commit` event, to get the final changelist number. It appears `change-submit` does not have access to the altered changelist number if the p4 server had to change it (["The Perforce service might renumber a changelist when you submit it, depending on other users' activities"](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/chapter.files.html#DB5-97074))

However, I would also like to revert the changelist if I'm unable to reach the downstream reporting tool (due to a momentary network issue). It seems `change-commit` is too late for this. If my trigger using `change-commit` returns a non-zero value here, the trigger fails, but the changelist is still committed.

Is there a way to combine these 2 requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get to the change-commit trigger, the change has been fully submitted, so no, you cannot halt the submit process at that point.

Frankly, halting a submit simply because a reporting tool is unavailable seems like an extreme response to a minor problem.

If the only thing wrong with the submit is that you couldn't reach the reporting service, perhaps you can record the changelist number in a queue locally, and have a retry mechanism that makes another attempt to notify the tool later.

This would make the two tools less tightly coupled.

A simple implementation would be to record "highest submitted changelist number successfully sent to the reporting tool" in the Perforce `counters` table using `p4 counter`, and then each time a change is submitted, check that counter, and send **all** the changelist numbers that had been submitted since the last time you successfully contacted the reporting tool.

Comment: Thanks. Missing records from the reporting tool is causing serious issues, so I'm not sure I'd describe it as a "minor problem", otherwise I'd agree it's overkill. Rejecting the submit was a low-impact fix, but it doesn't look like it's possibe. Cheers